# While merging audio, both the audio come linearly though I want it to overlay

Tags: ios, avassetwriter, avmutablecomposition, avcomposition, avvideocomposition

So, I try to use the following code in a 'for' loop to overlay the audio, but they are coming in linearly, with the last attached audio coming in first.

```
[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMake(5, 1)) ofTrack:audioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

I see that they have explaing all this in 2011 WWDC, session 415 - Working with media in AVFoundation and its solution will be there in AVEditIPadDemo example, but I am not able to get the access to that source too. It will be great if you can get me access to that code.
Thanks

Comment: can you post the full code you are using?

Comment: Hey @GauravSingh Thanks for replying, but I ended up using the the AVEditDemo code as it is, now even I dont know how it works :P